# Cors Error - MVC and Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC application which also uses webapi2.
To call the api services i am using jquery ajax as below.

```
$.ajax({
url: GetBaseURL() + '/api/MyController/PutMethod',
type: 'put',
data: dataObject,
contentType: 'application/json',
timeout: AJAX_TIMEOUT,
success: function () {
self.CallOtherFunction();
});
```

And the function getbaseURL returns content.url("~")
While this approach is working out from some pages, it's throwing the "Cross Origin Request Blocked : The same origin policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api/MyController/PutMethod" error.

I have tried googling out on cors but could not understand why I am facing this error, even though I have both MVC and Webapi under one solution, running through visual studio.

Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured your API to allow cross-origin requests? [This article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) explains how to set it up.

Comment: I am not supposed to do any changes in the code as the project is already up and running in the production without any issues. The CORS error doesnt seem appearing when the application is deployed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your WebApi. The projects could be in the same solution and only the port could be different and you would get the CORS error. To solve the WebApi problem you can read this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have checked this and unfortunately both webapi and website are configured to use the same port. Unable to find a way out. oops !

Answer (score 2):

if you facing this error while calling of an api in mvc then you follow the below steps

Step 1 :put this tags in your **web.config** file in api under the system.webServer tag.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, X-Your-Extra-Header-Key"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
```

Step 2- put this in **gloabl.asax.cs** file in your  webapi application

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.End();
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```